# Click on checkbox label not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox inside a P with class vertical options. I have written script to implement checkbox functionality even on clicking the P. The code is:

```
$(".vertical-options,.horizontal-options").click(function(event){
    var input = $(this).find('input').first();
    console.log(input);
    if((event.target.type !== 'checkbox') && (input.attr('type') === 'checkbox')) {
        if(input.is(':checked')){
            input.prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            input.prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
 });
```

but with this logic clicking on the checkbox label does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<label>` has a native behaviour that fits with your requirements. Just add an id to the checkbox and reffers in the tag: `<input type="checkbox" id="myID"><label for="myID">`, or if you don't want to put IDs you can wrap the checkbox in the label: `<label><input type="checkbox"> Your text</label>` and all your label will click the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `label` tag for this purpose. Write id of target checkbox in `for` attribute of `label` tag.

```html
<label for="id1">Checkbox-1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="id1" />

<label for="id2">Checkbox-2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="id2" />

<label for="id3">Checkbox-3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="id3" />
```

If you want to do this work using jquery for other tag, see example

```js
$("p").on("click", function(e){
    var checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    if ($(this).is(e.target)) 
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked')); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    Checkbox-1
    <input type="checkbox" />
</p>
<p>
    Checkbox-2
    <input type="checkbox" />
</p>
<p>
    Checkbox-3
    <input type="checkbox" />
</p>
```